# Installing ASP.Net SignalR on Deployment Server

Tags: asp.net, .net, signalr

I have a very simple asp.net signalr application, it is working fine on my local machine. But when I copy all these files to deployment server. It just stop working. I cant even access the url

website/signalr/hubs

The possible reason could be of some installation packages. I have several packages installed in my local machine in ProgramFiles/MicrosoftWebTools/Packages but there is none in deployment server.
Well I am not sure if this is the problem and even if it is then how to solve it.

Comment: What version of IIS are you running? If you're using a version before 8.0, you'll need to add extensionless URL support:  

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368/en-us

That's the most likely situation- if that's not the case, see the following document for other possible solutions:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/troubleshooting-and-debugging/troubleshooting

Comment: You don't install signalr on a deployment server. SignalR is a framework and "installation" happened when you put it into your project. 

I'm not sure how Program Files is relevant to the discussion. The better question is, can you host regular ASP.NET websites on your deployment server?

Comment: @dflower I am testing this SignalR application on the same server where I have hosted by ASP.net website and a WCF service. They are working fine.

Comment: Does your deployment server has .net 4.0 or later? How do you package your application to be sent to server?

Comment: @ShashankChaturvedi .Net framework is installed and its of version 4.5. I am trying both publish it using msdeploy and try to use XCopy as well.

Comment: I would like to confirm just one more thing are you publishing in release mode?

Comment: @ShashankChaturvedi I have tried it with both debug and release mode.

Comment: Can you hit an empty asp.net webpage on this webserver?

Comment: @PatrickFletcher: before 7.5, not 8.0

Comment: Maybe you can check this out: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/supported-platforms

Also I assume its a typo or it means the same but signalr mostly uses: ~signalr/hubs and not /signalr/hubs

Answer (score 0):

I was previously testing it on Windows Server 2008 R2. I still don't know how to make it work on this server(2008 R2). I have install Windows Server 2012 R2 and test the same application in it. It is working fine at my end.